What is the proper way to make a configurable split-supply voltage clamp with voltage dividers?
Being a beginner in electronics and not having had exposure to a lot of “best practices” I was trying to generalize the voltage clamp to arbitrary positive and negative clamping voltages. The objective of the simulation is to clamp a 5V-amplitude sine input between -2 V and +2 V. (I currently have no need for a contraption like this — this is an academic exercise.) My first attempt, the following,

works in the simulation, but is obviously not feasible because of the small resistors which are necessary to guide the “spill over” to ground. My question is whether the following solution attempt

which also works as intended in the simulation,

is the correct solution, or whether there is something that I am potentially overlooking. In particular, is there anything I have to keep in mind when attaching an actual load?

Is the source impedance of 100 Ohms specified for the problem?

No, I popped that in as generic current-limiting resistor when the input gets shorted to ground. There is no "problem" per se...well, it's a self-posed problem.

Okay. Well then the current compliance of the opamps isn't an issue. You can just increase that impedance if the opamps show any difficulties. Otherwise, all you've done is used the two opamps to create weak power supply rails for the diodes to clip against. Since this is a fairly loosely specified system, I can't ague with the approach you took. The opamps just buffer the voltage dividers and provide somewhat better current compliance (though of course you could just use very low-valued voltage divider resistors, too.) Diodes alone are soft clippers and you get rounded tops/bottoms.

If you reconfigure OA2 as an inverting amp, then you need only one voltage divider (R47 and R48).  Also, if you add in a pot, then a single adjustment point gets you variable,symmetrical clipping.
For example,
R47 = 2 K
R48 = 2 K
Between them is a 5 K linear pot with the wiper connected to the OA1 non-inverting input (and the OA2 unity-gain inverter).
Note - R43 might have to increase, to keep the signal source from overpowering the opamp output stages.
UPDATE - Another thought.
Maybe - OA1, OA2, R25, and R26 can be replaced with two emitter followers.  No base or collector resistors; just two transistors, one for each polarity.

Ah, that certainly makes sense. I didn't set out to create symmetric clipping, but I'm not sure I'd have thought of your approach myself. Good to know about taking care of the op-amp output...that was my concern: running the op-amp "in reverse."

The opamp datasheet should have specs for how much current the output stage can source and sink.  Usually it is in both the absolute max section and the recommended operating section.  See the Update for another approach.

You'll need to take care not to exceed the current sink/source ability of the op-amp. You shouldn't really ask for more than 10mA, which would occur if the voltage across R1 (R43) (100Ω) exceeded 1V.
Even though your simulation showed successful clipping, I suspect that in real life that op-amp would struggle to clamp when the input goes beyond ±3V or ±4V . I wouldn't trust CircuitLab to accurately reproduce this limitation of the TL081.
You can simulate and plot that current though, to see what I mean:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab
This is OA1's output current, for the 5V peak input waveform:

The TL081, and most common op-amps won't be able to produce the required 30mA while maintaining their output voltage fixed. However, if you increase R1 (R43) to 1kΩ, the current demand on the op-amp output is cut by a factor of ten, and the clamp would perform well up to inputs of around ±13V. If I set R1 to 1kΩ and increase V1 amplitude to 13V, this is OA1 output current:

11mA is a much more reasonable demand. It's fairly trivial to boost the op-amp's current capability, though, using a transistor:

simulate this circuit
Those transistors will sink and source all signal current directly to a supply rail, instead of the op-amp output, and the op-amp only has to provide a tiny fraction of that. I've changed R1 to be unnecessarily small, 10Ω, and yet clipping still happens just fine:

This is op-amp OA1's output current, down to 2mA or so, in spite of the 150mA flowing in R1 due to the 1.5V across it:

I'm not saying that design is good, it's really just to illustrate the issue you missed regarding limited op-amp output current capability.

Ha, ha! I completely forgot that sending the op-amp to the rails will clip the output. It always somehow struck me as "improper" to saturate an op-amp (even though it's standard business for a BJT acting as switch).

@Matthias There isn't a problem of output saturation, that's not what causes problems here. The op-amps are not saturated, just overloaded. We never ask them to output more voltage than they can, you are asking for more current than they are capable of, which is a different kind of problem, solved with the transistors.
